# python ibm_db for Linux env

Tags: python, linux, database, websphere

I am trying to download ibm_db library files for installing these library file as part of my python application. I am looking to deploy these files on a Linux system but the files in this tar for for WIN environment.

https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db/#files

Any suggestions on how I can find this app for Linux environment.

Thanks
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

You can in terminal and install using this `pip install ibm_db` This should automatically install the drivers needed. If it doesn't add to path then you could uninstall using `pip uninstall ibm_db` and use `python -m pip install ibm-db`

Comment: Not a very clear answer. How does this solve the Linux/Windows issue?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).